# Can anyone help me to get handle of process which is called by func Process.Start();?

Tags: c#, winforms, process, get, handle

For example, I wanna get handle from browser.

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Process.Start("https://google.com/");
            //How to get handle of this process?
            
        }
```

Comment: [`Process.Start`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.start?view=net-6.0#System_Diagnostics_Process_Start_System_String_) returns a `Process` object, and that in turn has a [`Handle`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.handle?view=net-6.0) property

Comment: `Process.Start` returns a `Process` object for the process it started, which has a `Handle` property. That said, browsers tend to display multiple pages inside a single process (as different tabs), and so if you've got a browser process running and you try and start a new one, the new one will probably tell the existing one to open the page as a new tab and then exit, which means the `Process` you get back from `Process.Start` might not live very long. There's not a lot you can do about this.

Comment: Yah. I knew that... So if I save a website browser as a file.html. Could I get it's handle? And that's true that if I keep only one window of browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Process.Start()` returns a `Process` object of the newly created process.

In the example below, `myProcess.Handle` is going to be the handle of said process.

```
var myProcess = Process.Start("notepad.exe");
Console.WriteLine(myProcess.Handle);
```

Comment: Just like _salt on chips_, answers are always better with a _description_, if only a one-liner.

Comment: Thanks for adding the salt.  :)  I hope you don't mind but I put your description on top.  +1

Comment: Ok I understood, thanks guys.